# Bash Scripting VIM commands

Tags: bash, scripting, vim, vi

I have a few files that I have an annoyingly repetitive group of VIM commands to apply to.
They are basic VIM commands just to delete some lines which are not supported by the process I need the files for.

Say I have a file called postgresdb.out

On this file I will

```
vim ./postgresdb.out
```

Then from inside VIM I will

```
:%s/old/new/g
```

and then

```
:g/deletethis/d
```

followed by

```
:%s/\n\n//g
```

then save the file and go about my day

I would like to know if it is possible to write a bash script that can do this process instead of retyping all the time

Comment: What is `:%s/\n\n//d` supposed to do? If I try it I get `Trailing characters` as the error message. So I think you either mean `g` or no modifier; or just do `:g/^$/d`. That said, I'd do this in perl using the `-i` and `-pe` options.

Comment: :%s/\n\n//d the d is a typo I fixed it above

Comment: If you must use Vim, look at Ex mode: http://superuser.com/questions/22455/vim-what-is-the-ex-mode-for-batch-processing-for

Comment: jasonwryan that is part one of the answer I was looking for, running vim with -E and EOF now to put it into a bash script

Answer (score 4):

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -i NONE -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode (`:help -s-ex`) messes up the Windows console, so you may have to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -i NONE -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the `"commands.ex"` file doesn't exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the `-` argument.

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-i NONE           Ignore the |viminfo| file (to avoid disturbing the
                user's settings).
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Answer (score 2):

automatic edition should be done using `sed(1)` (see `man sed` )

The commend your are looking for are

```
 sed -i -e s/old/new/g -e /deletethis/d -e '/^$/d' postgresdb.out
```

<strike>I am not sure what you expect with `:%s/\n\n//d`.</strike>

where

- `-i` means edit in place (usually sed will output edition do standard output)
- `-e` ... do the edition/deletion
- `-e '/^$/d'` shoudl delete empty lines

Comment: :%s/\n\n//d the d is a typo I fixed it above

Comment: `sed` didn't operate newline(s) `\n\n` (exept very new versions with option `-z`). If you'd like to remove empty lines try [wurtel](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/83831/wurtel) recipie `/^\s*$/d`